# How to disable CAS during development?

Tags: spring, spring-security, cas

We have integrated CAS using spring security. Is that possible to disable CAS during development or any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to know what you mean by "disable CAS". In our development environment, we use basic auth instead of CAS authentication. That is done very easily by having both filters in our configuration and a property to switch from basic auth entry point to CAS entry point.
Best regards,
Jérôme

Comment: Thats what i mean. But are you using spring security 3? Would you mind to show your implementation (for two different auth configuration and switch property) please? It would be great help.